# django Query set

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

i have a store and this store have an offers 
one of the offers
if you buy 5 pcs of this list of items, you will get discount 3 USD,
i tried to write a query,

but didn't work

```
o=order_products.objects.filter(order__id=1).values('product').annotate(Sum('qty'))
offers.objects.filter(products__id__in=o.values('product_id')).distinct(True)
```

now how can i match the Qty of this list of items are equal
to have this discount or multiple of

for example if he bought 5 pcs he will get discount 3 USD
if he bought 10 pcs he will get discount 6 usd
etc ...

```
class product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price=models.FloatField()

class order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class order_products(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(product)
    qty=models.IntegerField()
    order=models.ForeignKey(order)

class offers(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(product)
    qty = models.FloatField()
    discount_amount=models.FloatField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
from collections import Counter

order = order_products.objects.filter(order__id=1).values('product__pk')
product_count = dict(Counter(order))

discounts = {}

for id,count in product_count.iteritems():
  offer = offers.objects.filter(products__pk=id,qty=count)
  if offer.count():
     discounts[id] = offer.discount_amount

for id,discount in discounts.iteritems():
   print '%d of %s discounted by %0.3f' % (product_count[id],product.objects.get(pk=id).name,discount)
```